# How to render React components, stored in an array, inside the render method of another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've got a component, let's call *Screen*, which imports a component that will contain a search result. A method in Screen loops through an array of objects and for each object instaniates a new search result component and stores them in an array.

I'm new to React, so my question is, is it correct to create an instance of a class extending Component using the `new` keyword, or is there a proper React way to do this? If so what is the correct way of rendering these components in the Screen class, as the way I'm doing it in the snippet below doesn't seem to work as nothing renders.

**Screen.js** - I've cut down the file to just show what I'm on about

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

import SearchResult from "components/SearchResult";


class Screen extends Component {
    searchResultsComponents = [];

    submitSearchQuery(searchParam /* Array of objects */) {
        this.searchResultsComponents = [];
        for(let result in this.searchResults) {
            this.searchResultsComponents.push(new SearchResult(this.searchResults[result]));
            }
            this.forceUpdate();
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>  
                { this.searchResultsComponents.forEach((it) => { it.render(); }) }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Screen;
```

**SearchResult.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";


class SearchResult extends Component {
    title;
    setTitle(title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    description;
    setDescription(description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    constructor(searchResult) {
        super();
        this.setTitle(searchResult.snippet.title);
        this.setDescription(searchResult.snippet.description)
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text>{ this.title }</Text>
                <Text>{ this.description }</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default SearchResult;
```

Comment: dont call `new` on the component... just create the component instead `this.searchResultsComponents.push( <SearchResult {...this.searchResults[result]} />)` then in your render just render the array `<View>{this.searchResultsComponents}</View>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to approach this is, inside your render method:

```
 { this.searchResultsComponents.map((it, index) => <it key={index} />) }
```

The key is optional, but recommended by react to improve rendering performance when rendering an array of components.

See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component for more details.

Your approach does not work, because by just calling the render method, the HTML DOM is returned by the function call. However, you just call the function and don't do anything with the return value.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your approach doesn't work is that `forEach` method doesn't return anything. Instead of `forEach` use `map`. Your modified line should look something like this:

```
this.searchResultsComponents.map((component, index) => <View key={index}>{component}</View>);
```

The reason I wrapped the component into `View` is because this way each item can get `key` attribute which is [recommended when displaying arrays](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).